# Lambda function to replace all occurrences of a string in data table's rows

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, lambda, datatable

I have this:

```
Public Sub AssignDT(data_tables As Dictionary(Of String, DataTable))        
    Dim ApplicationDT = data_tables("Application")
End Sub
```

Now, this data table contains some columns whose values are upper case strings 'FALSE' or 'TRUE'. Is there a lambda function I can use to replace all those values with their lower case correspondents in c# or vb .net?

In Python, with dataframes, I got it like this, using a dict and replace function of the dataframe:

```
 booleanDictionary = {'TRUE': 'true', "FALSE":   'false'} 

 Application = data_frames['Application'].astype(object).replace(np.nan, 
  '').replace(booleanDictionary)
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop?  If you really want to go with LINQ then there's no standard extension method you can call, but you can call `ToList` and then call `ForEach` on that.  As always, the actual Lambda expression you pass to `ForEach` operates on a single item.  I would expect that can easily enough work out how convert a text value in a `DataRow` to lower-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Friend Module Main
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim oCol As DataColumn
    Dim oRow As DataRow

    Using oTable As New DataTable
      oCol = New DataColumn
      oTable.Columns.Add(oCol)
      oRow = oTable.NewRow
      oRow(0) = "FALSE"
      oTable.Rows.Add(oRow)

      Console.WriteLine(oRow(0))

      oTable.Select.ToList.ForEach(Sub(Row) Row(0) = CStr(Row(0)).ToLower)

      Console.WriteLine(oRow(0))
    End Using

    Console.Read()
  End Sub
End Module
```

Output:

```
FALSE
false
```

**--EDIT--**

If we don't have information about the columns, we can loop through the row's items and test for the value we need.

```
Friend Module Main
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim oColumns As List(Of DataColumn)
    Dim oRows As List(Of DataRow)
    Dim oRow As DataRow

    Using oTable As New DataTable
      oTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Weight", GetType(Integer)))
      oTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("IsHeavy", GetType(String)))
      oRow = oTable.NewRow
      oRow(0) = 123
      oRow(1) = "False"
      oTable.Rows.Add(oRow)
      oColumns = oTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).Where(Function(Column) Column.DataType = GetType(String)).ToList

      Console.WriteLine(oRow(1))

      oRows = oTable.Select.ToList
      oRows.ForEach(Sub(Row)
                      oColumns.ForEach(Sub(Column)
                                         If Boolean.TryParse(oRow(Column.Ordinal), Nothing) Then
                                           Row(Column.Ordinal) = CStr(oRow(Column.Ordinal)).ToLower
                                         End If
                                       End Sub)
                    End Sub)

      Console.WriteLine(oRow(1))
    End Using

    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you. Works. What if I don't know the column name or index, how can I be able to identify those strings and replace them with their lowercases correspondents?

Comment: @CatalinCernat ~ See my edit. It's not nearly as concise as the Python version, but that's what Python is for, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @CatalinCernat ~ p.s. Note also that the `Boolean.TryParse()` construct enables us to perform a case-insensitive replacement. Depending on your situation, it may be dangerous to rely on all values in that column being upper case.

Answer (score 1):

A VB.Net example, but not LAMBA:

```
Public Sub AssignDT(data_tables As Dictionary(Of String, DataTable))
    Dim ApplicationDT = data_tables("Application")
    For Each rw As DataRow In ApplicationDT.Rows
        For i As Int16 = 0 To ApplicationDT.Columns.Count - 1
            If ApplicationDT.Columns(i).DataType = GetType(String) Then
                If rw(i) = "FALSE" Then
                    rw(i) = "false"
                ElseIf rw(i) = "TRUE" Then
                    rw(i) = "true"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

alternatively

```
If rw(i) = "FALSE" OrElse rw(i) = "TRUE" Then rw(i) = rw(i).ToString.ToLower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dataTable` is a `System.Data.DataTable`, this will set all values of column `columnname` to lower case.

```
dataTable.Select().ToList().ForEach(x => x["columnname"] = x["columnname"].ToString().ToLower());
```